# Power Spectrum Definitions

Tags: statistics, solution-verification, definition, signal-processing, stationary-processes

Consider a stationary random process $x(n)$ with $n = 0, \pm 1, \pm 2,..$

The Autocorrelation function is defined as:
$$R_{xx}(m) := \mathbb{E}[x^*(n)x(n+m)]$$
where the * denotes conjugation.

I want to **prove the equivalence** of the following 2 **definitions of the power spectrum**.

1. Usual Definition
   $$P_{xx}(f) := \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}R_{xx}(k)e^{-j2\pi f k} = Y_1(f)$$
2. Alternative Definition
   $$P_{xx}(f) := \mathbb{E}[X(f) X^*(f)] = Y_2(f)$$
   where $X(f) = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}x(k)e^{-j2\pi f k}$

So I started out as follows:
\begin{align}
X(f)X^*(f) &= \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}x(k)e^{-j2\pi f k}\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}x^*(n)e^{j2\pi f n}\\
&= \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}x(k)x^*(n)e^{-j2\pi f (k-n)}
\end{align}
Then by setting $k-n = m$ we have:
\begin{align}
X(f)X^*(f) &=\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty}x^*(n)x(n+m)e^{-j2\pi f m}
\end{align}
Thus, if it is possible to interchange the expectation with the double sum
it follows:
\begin{align}
Y_2(f) &= \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty}R_{xx}(m)e^{-j2\pi f m}\\
&=\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}Y_1(f)
\end{align}

So it seems I have messed up the proof somewhere or the second definition is problematic. I suspect the former. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Here is a link to the pdf I was reading
https://labcit.ligo.caltech.edu/~rana/mat/HOSA/HOSA.PDF

Comment: Where did you see the second definition? It doesn't match what I've usually seen

Comment: @Snoop see page 14 of the pdf in the link above. It is the user's guide to HOSA toolbox of Matlab written by
Ananthram Swami, Jerry M. Mendel, Chrysostomos L. (Max) Nikias

Comment: Suspicious to me. $X$, as defined, may not converge at all.

Comment: I see what you mean, but maybe one should assume so. Because, after all, this is applied to a discrete signal with finite duration, to estimate the power spectrum. Anyways, if you have any suggestions on books that cover Higher Order Statistics they are much appreciated!